# How would I access my 2012 MacBook Air's Hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I recently spilled liquid on my 2012 13' macbook air (4,2) and now I would like to access the data that is (hopefully) still stored on my harddrive. What would I buy to read the data externally, as my laptop is currently not working. Is there a special wire or case that I have to get?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/macbook-air-faq/macbook-air-mid-2012-how-to-replace-upgrade-ssd-storage.html) claims that the drive is not officially user replaceable, but it’s simply a case of the connector being different.

But you say it’s the Mid 2012 model 4,2? That is the model number for the Mid 2011 model as per [the specifications listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Specifications). iFixit [has a good rundown](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2011+Solid-State+Drive/6371/1) on how to get to that one. And Other World Computing sells and external enclosure called the [Envoy](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOY/) that can take that internal SSD and make it an external USB 3.0 drive. Instructions on how to install a drive in [that Envoy enclosure are here as well](http://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/enc_owc_envoy/).